# half on the right and half on the left

Tags: php, html

I am currently trying to find a good solution for what to do with this

```
$all_products
```

this is an array with 7 products and i need to loop through them to create the dynamic page but i have kind of a structure issue with the page

```
<div class="left-pane left">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-pane left">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

How will I know how many to put in the right and the left and can i alternate between then or do i need to do something like (count($all_product) / 2) on the left and then the rest on the right pane. Also how do i loop only half on one side using. how do i find out what to do because the array will be different count every time

```
<?php foreach ($all_products as $product) { ?>
```

Comment: You might like this syntax if you're embedding PHP into HTML: `<?php foreach ($arr as $val): ?> <?php endforeach; ?>` - it's a bit nicer and more verbose than braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct each half separately by using something like:

```
$i = 0;
$left  = '<div class="right-pane left">';
$right = '<div class="right-pane right">';

foreach ($products as $product) {
    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
        $left  .= '<div class="item">' . $product . '</div>';
    } else {
        $right .= '<div class="item">' . $product . '</div>';
    }
}

$left  .= '</div>';
$right .= '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to give them all a fixed width and float them all left in a container of fixed width.

```
.item {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Here's a kickoff example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 3654173</title>
        <style>
            #items { 
                width: 600px;
            }
            .item {
                float: left;
                width: 300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="items">
            <div class="item">item1</div>
            <div class="item">item2</div>
            <div class="item">item3</div>
            <div class="item">item4</div>
            <div class="item">item5</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It will only go from left to right and then top to bottom, not the other way round as in your original question. Not sure if that hurts.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
$left = "";
$right = "";
foreach ($all_products as $product) {
   if($i%2==0) $left.= '<div class="item">'.$product.'</div>';
   else $right.= '<div class="item">'.$product.'</div>';
   $i++;
}
echo '<div class="left-pane left">'.$left.'</div>'.'<div class="right-pane left">'.$right.'</div>';
```